# Using Paredit to wrap existing expression

Tags: emacs, clojure, lisp, paredit

I'm using Emacs in Paredit mode for Lisp code.

I'm trying to wrap a function call in println:

```
(square 5)
(println (square 5))
```

What ends up happening in paredit is this:

```
(square 5)
(println) (square 5)
```

There is no way i can delete closing paren of println and move it to the end.

The way i'm doing it now is to:
1. delete function call and yank it within println
2. write println without paren, visually select code and enclose in parens

```
(square 5)
println (square 5)
=> select block of code and type (
(println (square 5))
```

Both of these approaches are tedious. This seems to be a common problem anytime i write code inside out in Paredit. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You'd probably do well to read the short [manual](http://mumble.net/~campbell/emacs/paredit.html), instead of asking questions for features that are well documented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`paredit-wrap-round` command may help (bound to M-( in the paredit version I use).

Comment: M-( results in (println) (square 5) if i type println first. I just realized i have to wrap around first and then type println which isn't natural. Thanks!

Comment: Wrapping the parameter before adding the function call is completely natural once you get used to writing lisp.

Answer (score 6):

In contrast to the other answers, I tend to use Ctrl-Right for this: after you get

```
(println|) (square 5)
```

(where `|` is where the cursor is), I simply press Ctrl-Right to get the correct result.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>M-(</kbd>

You can call `paredit-insert-html-examples` to generate a HTML webpage cheatsheet.  One version is [here](http://mumble.net/~campbell/emacs/paredit.html).

Answer (score 3):

Three ways to wrap a print form around a square form, in step-by-step progressions. (two ways of the three are already mentioned in other answers)

(1) Cut & type & paste

```
(+ (square 3) 4)
;;; make sure cursor is at right place (| is cursor)
(+ |(square 3) 4)
;;; mark-sexp and kill-region
(+ | 4)
;;; type the print form and make sure cursor is at right place
(+ (print |) 4)
;;; paste
(+ (print (square 3)) 4)
```

(2) type & slurf

```
(+ (square 3) 4)
;;; make sure cursor is at right place (| is cursor)
(+ |(square 3) 4)
;;; type the print form and make sure cursor is at right place
(+ (print|) (square 3) 4)
;;; paredit-forward-slurp-sexp
(+ (print (square 3)) 4)
```

(3) wrap & type

```
(+ (square 3) 4)
;;; make sure cursor is at right place (| is cursor)
(+ |(square 3) 4)
;;; paredit-wrap-round
(+ (|(square 3)) 4)
;;; type print
(+ (print (square 3)) 4)
```

Cut & type & paste is the most tedious. It doesn't depend on paredit and is the easiest to generalize to the case of wrapping a complex outer form around more than one inner forms which may be in multiline format, for example, turning

```
(let ((x 1))
  (moo)
  (oink)
  (oink))
```

into

```
(let ((x 1))
  (moo)
  (mapc (lambda (x)
          (oink)
          (oink))
        (list 1 2 3)))
```

by wrapping a mapc-over-lambda form around two oinks.

Type & slurf seems to be the most known. It can be generalized to the mapc-over-lambda case as well.

Wrap & type is the most easiest to type. When you generalize this to the map-over-lambda case, you select two oinks, and press `(` to wrap it, and finish writing the lambda form, and select the lambda form, press `(` to wrap it, type mapc, and you can use C-M-f to cross over the lambda form and type (list 1 2 3).

Answer (score 2):

In your case the solution is `M-2 M-(` or `M-( C-)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing this. The way that I normally do this is type

"("

which gets you

()println

and then C-S-) which gets you

(println)

The best way to use paredit to start is to have the paredit cheatsheet on a piece of paper stuck to the side of your monitor. Or, you could also install paredit-menu which adds a menu item with tooltips showing the same examples the cheetsheet does.

Answer (score 0):

I use M-C-(, which will immediately wrap the following sexp in parens.